# cmake: multiple compilers for different targets with single build command

Tags: cmake

I have read the answers in the questions:

1. [Using CMake with multiple compilers for the same language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542971/using-cmake-with-multiple-compilers-for-the-same-language)
2. [CMake: how to change compiler for individual target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168094/cmake-how-to-change-compiler-for-individual-target)

But I still don't understand the proper solution for cmake. The answer in [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168094/cmake-how-to-change-compiler-for-individual-target) works only with Ninja, not cmake. The answer in [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542971/using-cmake-with-multiple-compilers-for-the-same-language) concerns the basic concept without example. So for me, as a beginner in cmake, the solution using process_execute() is unclear in the terms of implementation.

Is it possible to create a top-level CMakeLists.txt with process_execute(), which can be used in the follow way:

1. Single `cmake` command in shell.
2. Single `make` command after `cmake` command for the project build.
3. Multiple targets with different compilers in one build.

What is the simple scheme of a such solution in this case?

**ADDITION**

My project consists from libA and libB. The libA is а backend, which emits code. The libB is a runtime support library for emitted code. I want to build the whole project by a standard "single" build command (cmake && make && make install). Of course the cmake command inlcudes parameters.

The libA may emits code for some processors. The libA may works in a cross mode. The libB is used for linking with emitted code. That is why the libB as a runtime library must be compiled in native mode.

When the libA is building in cross mode the build process must uses a one compiler for the libA, and a second compiler for the libB. In my opinion the splitting of the build process into two separated commands ("cmake1 && make1" for libA and "cmake2 && make2" for libB) is a "logical" error.

Also it is useful if the single build command may builds a multiple number of version libB for different processors.

**ADDITION2**

possible solution: [using add_subdirectory()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76317970/10202693)

Comment: The command [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) performs actions **immediately**, while `cmake` is run. For defer actions until the build stage (when `make` is run) you could use the command [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add). Whatever approach you would use, the COMMAND's for them means just the shell commands for execute. I am not sure what is unclear for you. Could you show (add to the question post) your **attempt** in using these functionality?

Comment: "_Multiple targets with different compilers in one build._" out of curiosity, why? why not just generate multiple buildsystems? is there a reason you _can't_?

Comment: "*multiple buildsystems*": tried to explain my motivation in **ADDITION**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a simplest solution for me via my current cmake user level.
(Based on [The canonical way ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75777519/10202693))

*libb.cmake:*

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CC_ARCH})
add_library(libb_${X_ARCH} static ${libb_SOURCE})
```

*targets/x86_64/CMakeLists.txt:*

```
inlcude(../../libb.cmake)
```

*targets/mips64el/CMakeLists.txt:*

```
inlcude(../../libb.cmake)
```

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
...
foreach ( X_ARCH IN LISTS ARCHS_TO_BUILD)
    set(CC_ARCH ...)
    add_subdirectory(targets/${X_ARCH})        
endforeach()
```

So a follow build command causes the using different compilers at a one build. (The specification of (cross-)compilers is taking out of context.) The using a multiple number of compilers becomes possible by add_subdirectory().

```
$ cmake -DARCHS_TO_BUILD="x86_64;mips64el" && make
```

File 'libb.cmake' works as the macro definition and files 'targets/*/CMakeLists.txt' work as the instance of definitions.

Answer (score 1):

since CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER is singleton variable for each lang, we can never  assign different compilers to targets with same language *in "One CMake Progress"*. Thus the cmake is nearly no more than a script launcher.

But there is a little things cmake can do.
cmake is also a build-system based on dependencies. so you may achieve what you want by declare custom_target, see [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html). which i thought is better than output-insensitive process_execute。

Comment: The original goal is getting the build system for some backend (may be cross) and a set of runtime-support native libraries for each processor (from given build's set). Where the backend is building by base compiler, and runtime-support libraries are building by self-specific compilers.

Comment: Currently I am "reinventing the wheel" using shell-script and direct Makefiles. But I want to use cmake as a build system.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/September007/resources/blob/ffmpeg-cmake/CMakeLists.txt) is a example which wrap process of "configure + make" into cmake. 

you can consider the <B>COMMAND ${CONFIG_COMMAND}</B> as the place which you can actually set the things like compiler up(make -DCXX_COMPILER=gcc-old -Dbinrary_dir=build/gcc-old)

sorry for the example, which only may work in linux( too lazy to support others :( )