CMake embedded project with different target for unit tests
My project's target is an embedded MCU. I cross-compile on my host.
I want to write unit tests, and include them in my cmake project structure. The unit tests are for testing module logic, so not running on the target but on the host.
Here is an illustrating structure:
| application.c
| CMakeLists.txt
+ utils/
    | filter.c
    | filter.h
    + tests
        | test_filter.c
        | CMakeLists.txt

I can build an embedded application that uses application.c, and filter.[ch].
From what I have gathered online, this is my attempt to include the building of the tests for the host architecture:

added this to the root's CMakeLists.txt:

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(utils/test)


added this to the tests/CMakeLists.txt:

add_executable(test_filter test_filter.c)
project(filter_test C)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")
add_compile_options(
    "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-O0;-DNDEBUG;-std=c99;-Wall;-Werror>"
)

add_test(NAME test_filter
          COMMAND test_filter)

My main issue so far, is that the flags of the embedded project follow for the compilation of the test program.
The compilation flags for my cross-compiling (arm-none-eabi-gcc, e.g. -mthumb, -mcpu) don't make sense for my host's compiler (regular gcc). It also tries to build in  libraries irrelevant to the tests:
make[2]: Leaving directory '/projroot/build'
[  2%] Performing build step for 'ELF2UF2Build'
[  2%] Building C object utils/test/CMakeFiles/test_filter.dir/test_filter.c.obj
[  3%] Performing build step for 'PioasmBuild'
[  4%] Built target bs2_default
gcc: warning: '-mcpu=' is deprecated; use '-mtune=' or '-march=' instead
make[3]: Entering directory '/projroot/build/elf2uf2'
make[2]: Entering directory '/projroot/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/projroot/build/pioasm'
[ 11%] Built target freertos
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-mthumb'


How do I setup my tests directory and the relevant CMakeLists.txt, for cmake to build the tests for my host architecture, rather than the embedded MCU?

When I did embedded development, we just built the middleware parts locally and ran the tests that way.  Is that an option?  You can obviously still package/run cross-compiled tests on the target platform.

Thank you @StephenNewell. I have also always written my own makefiles for such unit tests in the past. I'm new to cmake and thought there would be a flexible appropriate way to do this, as having raw manually written makefiles in an otherwise cmake project might be... surprising.

I used cmake for everything, I just built twice.  Local builds until the middleware worked, then a cross build to make sure I got the same results on the target hardware.

How did you point out the different target architecture (and flags) for the different builds (test on host vs target hw)?

Most of the code was middleware and ran everywhere with a C++ compiler.  The platform-specific stuff was enabled/disabled with cmake options, so it was really just a matter of calling cmake with the right flags.

You cannot use different compiler for different targets in the same CMake project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168094/cmake-how-to-change-compiler-for-individual-target. You may configure your CMake project twice, once for the target machine, and once for the host.

@Tsyvarev That is a bummer, but thanks a lot for pointing this out. Then I have an excuse for using a manually created Makefile, which is my personal preference anyway!
