# Setting CMake variables in a function

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to write a CMake function that creates an object library of LLVM bitcode files. Here is what I have so far

```
function(build_llvm_lib OUTPUT SRC)
  if(NOT LLVM_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "LLVM build requested but LLVM not found")
  endif()

  set(SRCS ${SRC} ${ARGN})

  set(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".bc")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".bc")
  set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".bc")

  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -emit-llvm")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -emit-llvm")

  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${LLVM_TOOLS_BINARY_DIR}/clang)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${LLVM_TOOLS_BINARY_DIR}/clang++)
  set(CMAKE_AR ${LLVM_TOOLS_BINARY_DIR}/llvm-ar)
  set(CMAKE_RANLIB ${LLVM_TOOLS_BINARY_DIR}/llvm-ranlib)

  add_library(${OUTPUT} OBJECT ${SRCS})
endfunction(build_llvm_lib)
```

However, the problem that I'm having is that even though I am setting the CMake variables like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_CXX_OUTPUT_EXTENSION` these don't seem to be having any affect (i.e. they are being ignore) when CMake is run. When I look at the generated Makefile these settings don't appear and when I run make a regular object file is built rather than an LLVM bitcode file.

I'm kind of a CMake newb, so can someone please explain what's going on here? Is there some sort of misunderstanding I'm making here with CMake functions?

Comment: You need to add `PARENT_SCOPE`, cf. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set.html

Comment: Excellent, thanks! For some reason `CMAKE_<LANG>_OUTPUT_EXTENSION` is still being ignored, but some Googling seems to show that this is not unusual. I don't _really_ understand why `PARENT_SCOPE` works though. Won't this mean that when `build_llvm_lib` returns future calls to `add_library` (outside of this function) will also create LLVM bitcode files, rather than regular object files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While all CMake variables may have different values when you create different targets, CMake expects some of variables be the same for **all targets**. Examples of those variables:

- *CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER*
- *CMAKE_AR*
- *CMAKE_RANLIB*
- *CMAKE_<LANG>_OUTPUT_EXTENSION*

This means that you **cannot use different compilers** for different targets in the same project. See, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542971/using-cmake-with-multiple-compilers-for-the-same-language).

Variables *CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS* also should be defined globally, for all targets.

Only CMake variables and functions which are propagated to the *target's property* have *per-target meaning*.

For example, you may define additional compiler options for concrete targets using commands `add_compile_options`, `add_definitions` or by manually setting target's **properties** *COMPILE_FLAGS* or *COMPILE_DEFINITIONS*.

---

In your `build_llvm_lib` function body only *CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX* variable probably has *per-target* nature: while it is not stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html), I suspect it just sets [SUFFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/SUFFIX.html) property for newly-defined targets.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so if I understand you correctly I should not be using this approach to begin with? And I would be better off following the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542971/using-cmake-with-multiple-compilers-for-the-same-language) and run CMake twice?

Comment: Yes, it is better to create distinct project for create libraries with llvm.