# CMake add_subdirectory use different compiler

Tags: c, cmake, nasm

I have a CMake project that consists of several sub-projects added to the main project using `add_subdirectory` function.
I use a custom compiler for which I created a helper file which sets the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER` to compile all the sub-projects.
The problem I am facing is that I need to add another sub-project which needs to use a different compiler and it seems that CMake can only use a single compiler for all sub-projects.

Is there a way to configure a different compiler for one of the sub-projects added by `add_subdirectory()` command?

I tried to configure the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable for each sub-project, but somehow this variable seems to be cached and used for all the projects.

The beginning of each CMakeLists.txt sub-project:

```
include(cmake/Toolchain.cmake)
```

Part of cmake/Toolchain.cmake file:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${MY_COMPILER}")
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "${MY_ASSEMBLER}")
```

I expect my application to be compiled with the newly configured compiler but, instead it uses the old compiler.

Comment: As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9545369/3440745) to the duplicate question said, you **cannot** use different compilers withing a single CMake project.